# DAPL errors on Azure RDMA-enabled SLES cluster

Tags: azure

I set up 2 Azure A8 VMs in an availability set running SLES-HPC 12 (following the tutorial here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-cluster-rdma/).

When I run the Intel MPI pingpong test, I am getting DAPL errors:

```
azureUser@sshvm0:~> /opt/intel/impi/5.0.3.048/bin64/mpirun -hosts 10.0.0.4,10.0.0.5 -ppn 1 -n 2 -env I_MPI_FABRICS=shm:dapl -env I_MPI_DYNAMIC_CONNECTION=0 -env I_MPI_DAPL_PROVIDER=ofa-v2-ib0 /opt/intel/impi/5.0.3.048/bin64/IMB-MPI1 pingpong
sshvm1:d28:bef0eb40: 12930 us(12930 us):  dapl_rdma_accept: ERR -1 Input/output error
sshvm1:d28:bef0eb40: 12946 us(16 us):  DAPL ERR accept Input/output error
[1:10.0.0.5][../../src/mpid/ch3/channels/nemesis/netmod/dapl/dapl_conn_rc.c:622] error(0x40000): ofa-v2-ib0: could not accept DAPL connection request: DAT_INTERNAL_ERROR()
Assertion failed in file ../../src/mpid/ch3/channels/nemesis/netmod/dapl/dapl_conn_rc.c at line 622: 0
internal ABORT - process 0
```

Similar errors when running one of the OSU MPI microbenchmarks (compiled with impi compiler):

```
azureUser@sshvm0:~> /opt/intel/impi/5.0.3.048/bin64/mpirun -hosts 10.0.0.4,10.0.0.5 -ppn 1 -n 2 -env I_MPI_FABRICS=shm:dapl -env I_MPI_DYNAMIC_CONNECTION=0 -env I_MPI_DAPL_PROVIDER=ofa-v2-ib0 /opt/intel/impi/5.0.3.048/bin64/IMB-MPI1 pingpong
sshvm1:d28:bef0eb40: 12930 us(12930 us):  dapl_rdma_accept: ERR -1 Input/output error
sshvm1:d28:bef0eb40: 12946 us(16 us):  DAPL ERR accept Input/output error
[1:10.0.0.5][../../src/mpid/ch3/channels/nemesis/netmod/dapl/dapl_conn_rc.c:622] error(0x40000): ofa-v2-ib0: could not accept DAPL connection request: DAT_INTERNAL_ERROR()
Assertion failed in file ../../src/mpid/ch3/channels/nemesis/netmod/dapl/dapl_conn_rc.c at line 622: 0
internal ABORT - process 0
```

What is the cause of these errors? How do I fix and run these microbenchmarks? Thanks for any help!

I did also already verify SSH connectivity between the 2 nodes by running "mpiexec -machinefile machinefile -n 2 hostname"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to update RDMA drivers.  We have updated the documentation follow the link below
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-cluster-rdma/

Please go to the section 
Update the Linux RDMA drivers for SLES 12

Please follow the instructions and update the RDMA drivers.  Please update the drivers ONLY if you have provisioned VM's in one of the following regions
US EAST
US NORTH CENTRAL
US SOUTH CENTRAL
NORTH EUROPE

Comment: Excellent, pingpong test looks good now. I appreciate the ARM instructions too! Thanks!